# mvc5 model which is posted with html.beginform is missing some properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this model which I'm using in a view:

```
using (var db = new FieldSaverContext())
{
    AspNetUser user = (from p in db.AspNetUsers
                       where p.Id == id
                       select p).Include(m => m.AspNetRoles) .First();
    model.AUser = user;

    List<AspNetRole> roles = (from r in db.AspNetRoles
                              select r).ToList();
    model.RoleList = roles;

    List<ListID> ids = (from l in db.ListIDs
                        select l).ToList();
    model.ListIDList = ids;

    List<ViewerList> viewerLists = (from v in db.ViewerList
                                    select v).ToList();
    model.ViewerList = viewerLists;

}
```

This is how my view looks like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Users"))
{
  <div class="container containerEdit">
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AUser.Id)
          <label>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.AUser.Id)</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.AUser.FirstName)
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AUser.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AUser.PhoneNumber)
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AUser.PhoneNumber)
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ListIDList)
          @Html.DropDownListFor(n => n.ListIDList, new SelectList(Model.ListIDList, "ID", "Value"))
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AUser.Note1)
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AUser.Note1)
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AUser.Note2)
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AUser.Note2)
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="form-group">
          @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AUser.LastName)
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AUser.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AUser.Email)
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AUser.Email)
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Report Viewer</label>
          @Html.DropDownListFor(v => v.AUser.ViewerId, new SelectList(Model.ViewerList, "ID", "Value"))
        </div>
      </div>
      @Html.HiddenFor(v => v.AUser.Id)
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      @foreach (AspNetRole role in Model.RoleList)
      { @Html.CheckBox(role.Name, Model.AUser.AspNetRoles.Any(userRole => userRole.Id == role.Id)) @Html.Label(role.Name)<br /> }
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btnSaveEdit" value="Save" />
  </div>
}
```

When the postback is happening, I'm able to get the values for the AUser but I'm not getting any of the values for the Model.RoleList which is used in checkbox.
I want to check which checkboxes are checked from the RoleList and assign those roles to the User.

What am I missing?

### Update

Edit Action(s):

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    ManageViewModel model = new ManageViewModel();

 
        using (var db = new DbContext())
        {
            AspNetUser user = (from p in db.AspNetUsers
                               where p.Id == id
                               select p).Include(m => m.AspNetRoles) .First();
            model.AUser = user;

            List<AspNetRole> roles = (from r in db.AspNetRoles
                                      select r).ToList();

            model.RoleList = roles;

            List<ListID> ids = (from l in db.ListIDs
                select l).ToList();

            model.ListIDList = ids;

            List<ViewerList> viewerLists = (from v in db.ViewerList
                select v).ToList();

            model.ViewerList = viewerLists;

        }
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ManageViewModel model)
{
    AspNetUser user = model.AUser;

    using (var db = new DbContext())
    {
        AspNetUser dbUser = (from u in db.AspNetUsers
            where u.Id == model.AUser.Id
            select u).First();

        dbUser.FirstName = model.AUser.FirstName;
        dbUser.LastName = model.AUser.LastName;
        dbUser.Email = model.AUser.Email;
        dbUser.PhoneNumber = model.AUser.PhoneNumber;

        dbUser.Note1 = model.AUser.Note1;
        dbUser.Note2 = model.AUser.Note2;
        dbUser.ViewerId = model.AUser.ViewerId;

        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Did you check that the `model.RoleList` was effectively not empty?

Comment: @Groyoh its not empty http://gyazo.com/49be65623d5c76e5f71f085968b31ae9

Comment: Ok, and what do you mean exactly by "I'm not getting any of the values for the Model.RoleList"? Is no markup generated or are the checkbox values incorrects?

Comment: When I'm clicking the submit button, in the controller I'm not able to get the values of the Model.RoleList, its null @Groyoh.

Comment: Oh I think I got it. Could you edit your question to show the `Edit` action? Once I have that, I will post an anwser that might fix your issue.

Comment: @Groyoh Edit action added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the roles are not bound to your view model. So here's what you have to do:

- Create a new role view model:

  ```
  public class RoleViewModel
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }   
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- Modify your `ManageUserViewModel` to have a list of `RoleViewModel` instead of `AspNetRole`:

  ```
  public class ManageUserViewModel
  {
    public List<RoleViewModel> Roles { get; set;}
    // Your other properties
  }
  ```
- Change your edit to set the `Roles` property from the available roles:

  ```
  public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
  {
     // beginning of your action
     List<AspNetRole> roles = from r in db.AspNetRoles
                              select r;
     model.Roles = new List<RoleViewModel>();
     foreach(AspNetRole role in roles){
       model.Roles.Add(new RoleViewModel { 
         Id = role.Id, 
         Name = role.Name,
         Selected = user.AspNetRoles.Any(userRole => userRole.Id == role.Id)
       });
     }
     // end of your action
  }
  ```
- Change your other action to

  ```
   public ActionResult Edit(ManageViewModel model){
    // beginning of your action
    // remove roles from user
    List<AspNetRoles> newRoles = new List<AspNetRoles>();
    foreach(RoleViewModel role in model.Roles){
      newRole.Add(db.AspNetRoles.Find(role.id))
    } 
    // set your user roles from newRoles
    // end of your action 
  }
  ```
- In your view change the checkbox part by :

  ```
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Roles)
  ```
- And finally create a `Shared/EditorTemplate/RoleViewModel.cshtml` file :

  ```
  @model RoleViewModel
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Selected)
  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
  ```

Comment: this is what I'm getting for the checkboxes using your example: http://gyazo.com/d30dfd748c8218554071230091eec6ef

Comment: I made a typo in my answer. Change `EditorTemplate` folder to `EditorTemplates` with an 's' and make sure that this folder go in the `Views/Shared` folder.

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace your `@foreach (AspNetRole role in Model.RoleList)` with `for` loop
2. Refactor your `AspNetRole` viewModel to contain `Selected` property

   ```
   public class AspNetRole
   {
      public int Id { get; set; }   
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public bool Selected { get; set; } // <- new property
   }
   ```
3. Remove `AspNetRoles` from yout `ViewModel`
4. You will receive the list of selected items on form post

See sample https://dotnetfiddle.net/QbUxi0

Comment: same null @max-brodin

Comment: That new property 'Selected' does not exist in the AspNetRole table, its part of the Asp.Net Identity, Should I add that column manually? HANKS

Comment: I think the best solution is to introduce new classes `RoleViewModel`, `UserViewModel` and convert from `Model` classes to `ViewModel`

Comment: Do you have idea why with the current code I'm not able to get the role values but I'm able to get the user values? Thanks

Comment: First of all `foreach` is not supported for nested models.

Comment: @Laziale, Look at the html you are generating. You have multiple checkboxes and associated hidden inputs with values of `true` and `false` and name attributes that have no relationship to your model properties which is why it wont bind.